# scandir in php with special (hungarian) characters

Tags: php

I've been trying to read (image) files a folder in my website. But, there's a problem! There are some special hungarian character (like: á,í,ú,ű,ó,é, etc...) in the name of the folder which I want to read. I've been trying many mode, but it doens't work. My php code:

```
<?php
        $images = scandir("images/2005/avatás/");
        foreach($images as $file) {
            print($file);
        }
?>
```

I've been trying to fix the problem, with mb_convert_encoding(), urlencode(), urldecode() functions, but these couldn't help me.

Have you got any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Oy :/ I would always recommend that people stay away from any "special" characters in folder/file names on a linux based system. I would even go as far as to say don't use spaces (or any whitespace characters) as these would need to be escaped.

Comment: I understand, and I had known, but, I want to write to the page, the names of files and folders :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iconv("windows-1254", 'UTF-8', $foldername)
```

Same problem same language, I assume this should work for you too

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)

```
<?php
$folder = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", "images/2005/avatás/");
$images = scandir($folder);
foreach($images as $file) {
    print($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your reply, but the result had been this:Warning: scandir(images/2005/avatГЎs/,images/2005/avatГЎs/): in C:\wamp\www\toparti\betolt.php on line 19