# how to use UTF8 character in path Address for Scandir php

Tags: php, utf-8, yii, yii2

how to use UTF8 character in path Address for Scandir php

my folder name is: **61-تست تست**

i have error in scandir and DirectoryIterator.

after change folder name to **61** fix my problem but in need full name.

```
$folder = '61-تست تست';
        $path    = 'files/'.$folder;

print_r(scandir($path));

        foreach (new \DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
            if(!$file->isDir())
            {
                echo $file->getFilename() . "<br>";
            }
        }
```

error:

```
    UnexpectedValueException

The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

DirectoryIterator::__construct(D:/wamp64/www/project/web/files/61-تست تست,D:/wamp64/www/project/web/files/61-تست تست): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)
```

Comment: سلام. این دوتا لینک رو یه نگاهی بنداز:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990072/scandir-in-php-with-special-hungarian-characters
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544772/readdir-and-scandir
بعدش گوگل رو هم بگرد، حتما کسی بوده با این مشکل برخورده باشه:
https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&q=utf8+Scandir+php&oq=utf8+Scandir+php&gs_l=serp.3...90157.97443.0.100148.7.7.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.0.0.uRgxw9rYKHs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&biw=1024&bih=662&ech=1&psi=5YlqWfWOJ8PVwQLFzZnIDw.1500154339585.3&ei=5YlqWfWOJ8PVwQLFzZnIDw&emsg=NCSR&noj=1
موفق باشی

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScanDir good work in PHP 5.6 **LINUX** but upload files only with FTP and dont work in PHP 5.6 windows for fix this in windows you are use WFIO ext or Upgrade to PHP 7.1

Comment: Yes, scandir works with accented characters only if php version >= 7.1. You make my day )))